# create a bubble plot (or something similar) from cluster analysis in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, cluster-analysis

The following data frame is an example of a result from a clustering analysis and I would like to create a visualization. I'm thinking of a bubble plot that takes the column total into account, but it should also print the value for var1. No idea how to do this and unfortunately I cannot add the expected result (basically because I'm not sure whtat I'm looking for ;-). So basically, for each cluster, I would like a bubble that scales with the variable total and that bubble should also contain the values from var1.

```
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(cluster = rep(1:3,5),
                  var1 = sample(rep(LETTERS[1:10]),15,replace =TRUE),
                  total = sample(30:300,15, replace=TRUE))
```

Comment: Some of your `var1` values appear more than once in the same cluster with different values (eg, `"G"` is in cluster `3` 3 times) or in different clusters (eg, `"A"` is in both cluster `1` and cluster `3`). You should probably remove `replace = TRUE` from the `sample()` call that generates `var1`. But even better would be to `dput()` your actual clustering results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`plotly` is a great tool for making graphs interactive. Instead of writing text to the bubble, which can be hard to read, `plotly` allows for you to hover over points and display text. Try something like:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)

set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(cluster = rep(1:3,5),
                  var1 = sample(rep(LETTERS[1:10]),15,replace =TRUE),
                  total = sample(30:300,15, replace=TRUE))

plt <- ggplot2::ggplot(df, aes(x=cluster, y=var1, size = total, text=paste('</br>var1: ',var1,'</br>total: ',total))) +
    geom_point(alpha=0.7)

ggplotly(plt)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! But when I try to run your code I get the following error: Error in train(..., self = self) : 
  unused argument (list("cluster", "var1", "total", "paste(\"</br>var1: \", var1, \"</br>total: \", total, \"</br>1: \", ..."))

Comment: Hi, I've attached a picture of what I ran. From your error message, it seems you have some other train function which is causing this issue.